# Populating a dropdownlist from ViewModel by making a call to a service layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to populate a dropdownlist from a view model that in turn will be making a call to a service layer which is in different project but within same solution.  However the dependency in service layer is fed from a constructor via UnityFramework. So this has made the task a bit complicated. 
One way to achieve might be to make the method static and directly call the service method from the class without creating an instance of it. However i feel this is not the right way>

So what would be the best way to make that call and populate the dropdownlist from view model.
I know the same dropdownlist can be populated from HttpGet(shown in the code) and HttpPost controllers but i feel
that is a bit of a overkill.

Here is my Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        CarViewModel model = new CarViewModel();           
        var colourList = _service.GetAllColours();
        model.ColourList = colourList.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.description,
            Value = x.id.ToString()
        }).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class CarViewModel
{          
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Reg No")]
    public string RegNo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter colour")]
    public int Colour { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ColourList
    {
        get;  //How can i make a service call from here? and get rid of set keyword.
        set;
    }             
}
```

Code from the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","CarRental",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)       

@Html.LabelFor(x=>x.Colour)
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Colour,Model.ColourList,"Please Make a Selection")    
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.Colour)    

<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton"/>
}
```

Code from the service layer which is in different project but within same solution

```
public class DAO 
{
    private   CarRentalEntities _entities;       
    public DAO(CarRentalEntities entities)
    {
        _entities = entities;
    }

    public  List<Colour> GetAllColours()
    {
        List<Colour> colours = (from c in _entities.Colours select c).ToList<Colour>();
        return colours;
    }      
}
```

Comment: Are you also using the same ViewModel to pass data back to the contorller? (POST)

Comment: Hi Yorro. Yes its the same View Model

Comment: In my opinion, it seems like you're over thinking it. The role of the controller in an MVC application should be, among others, to prepare the view for display. Another opinion of mine, is that viewmodels should have as little logic as possible, and remain POCOs. A compromise that might work you, would be to create a static mapping class, that has methods which take the data as parameters, and spit out the populated viewmodels.